# Ansible Playbook execution in Docker container skipping task completion

Tags: docker, ansible

I am trying to Dockerize a ansible playbook that runs a MySQL dump.

```
---
- name: MySQL Dump
  hosts: lh
  connection: local
  vars_files:
    - ./vars/sql-credentials.yml
    - ./vars/aws-credentials.yml

  tasks:
    - name: Create Folder To Store
      file:
        state: directory
        path: ./backups

    - name: Get Dump from MySQL DB
      mysql_db:
        name: "{{ db_name }}"
        config_file: .my.cnf
        login_host: "{{ db_login_host }}"
        login_user: "{{ db_login_user }}"
        login_password: "{{ db_login_password }}"
        state: dump
        target: "backups/z-{{ ansible_date_time.date }}.sql.gz"
```

Executing the playbook outside of the container, I get the sql dump file that I am expecting (dump file is about `80mb`). When the playbook runs inside the container, it does the playbook finishes early (almost immediately after task was listed) without any errors, the output of the file is `20kb`.

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic

RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get dist-upgrade -y && \
  apt-get install -y software-properties-common systemd && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN apt-add-repository -y ppa:ansible/ansible && apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    ansible \
    mysql-client \
    python-pip \ 
    python-dev \ 
    build-essential \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY . .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN echo "[local]\nlocalhost ansible_connection=local" > /etc/ansible/hosts

CMD [ "ansible-playbook", "-i", "inventory", "playbook.yml", "-vvvv" ]
```

I've tried running it in verbose mode inside the container, and I'm not getting any errors at all.

The reason why I want to have this run in a container is because I want Travis CI to execute this dump in a CRON and then deploy it to a S3 bucket.